# Cant draw using glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

Why isn't this code working?

```
 // 1 square (made by 4 quads) to be rendered
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x, y,
    x+w, y,
    x+w, y+h,
    x, y+h,
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_position);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

I am using glew with this and i get no compile errors, all i get is nothing drawn on the screen.

if i use this instead it works fine:

```
glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);

    glScalef(scale,scale,1);
    //set color
    glColor4f(R, G, B, A);

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        glTexCoord2f(  texLeft,    texTop );
        glVertex2f( x, y );

        glTexCoord2f( texRight,    texTop );
        glVertex2f( x+w, y );

        glTexCoord2f( texRight, texBottom );
        glVertex2f( x+w, y+h );

        glTexCoord2f(  texLeft, texBottom );
        glVertex2f( x, y+h );

    glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: I got a 2D setup with OpenGL i don't understand where it'd be culled. Especially since if i replace the code with immediate mode it works fine.

Comment: True, it doesn't look like that would be consistent now that you posted that. All I was going off of is that OpenGL does backface culling by default and it can be a pain when it's just being culled, not something actually wrong.

Comment: I think it's getting drawn, but it's getting drawn all black, try to add a call to glColor4f before the one to glDrawArrays

Comment: I have a tile array drawn behind it. So any color at all would show up on the screen. But that was my first though too but the call made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm stupid... 
I specified to use texture but never bound any to the vertextes...

This code works just fine:

```
GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
    x, y,
    x+w, y,
    x+w, y+h,
    x, y+h,
};
GLfloat texture_coord[] = {
    texLeft, texTop,
    texRight, texTop,
    texRight, texBottom,
    texLeft, texBottom,
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_position);

glEnableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texture_coord);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState( GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY );
glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

Comment: it happens to all of us, the important thing is that you found out what was causing this issue

Comment: Yeah, this was driving me insane. So glad it's working now. VBO's next! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Workin' fine here:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

bool vertexArray = false;
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 't' ) vertexArray = !vertexArray;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    double winWidth = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double winHeight = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    double ar = winWidth / winHeight;
    glOrtho( -1 * ar, 1 * ar, -1, 1, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    float x = -0.5f;
    float y = -0.5f;
    float w = 1;
    float h = 1;
    float scale = 1;

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    glScalef(scale,scale,1);
    //set color
    glColor4f( 1, 0, 0, 1 );

    if( vertexArray )
    {
        GLfloat vertices_position[] = {
            x, y,
            x+w, y,
            x+w, y+h,
            x, y+h,
        };

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices_position);
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }
    else
    {
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
        glVertex2f( x, y );
        glVertex2f( x+w, y );
        glVertex2f( x+w, y+h );
        glVertex2f( x, y+h );
        glEnd();
    }

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glewInit();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tired it without the texture-coords with immediate mode and it didn't draw an image... so i guess i have to define the texture-coords for the array to work!